# Using pre-populated database,it gives my activity has stopped

Tags: java, android, database

I am adding one existing database in my assets folder,after that those data has to be copy and then create new database and then stored locally,In that new database i can also add.
I am showing those data in my listview activity also. Now my activity has stopped.

My db activity.

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        openDataBase();
}

public void createDataBase() {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (!dbExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error");
                throw new Error("Error copying database!");
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Database already exists");
        }
    }
    //
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
        try {
            String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Error while checking db");
        }

        if (checkDb != null) {
            checkDb.close();
        }
        return checkDb != null;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {





        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;


        OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);


        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);      }

        localDbStream.close();
        externalDbStream.close();

    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        if (mDb == null) {
            createDataBase();
            mDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        }
        return mDb;
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                  + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+ DATABASE_TABLE_PROJ);
        onCreate(db);
    }


}

    public void saveCategoryRecord(Category category) {

         ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
         values.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE , category.getTitle());
         values.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT, category.getContent()); 

         values.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_DATE, category.getDate());
         // Inserting Row
         mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_PROJ, null, values);
         mDb.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    public Cursor fetchProject(long rowId) throws SQLException {

        Cursor mCursor =

                mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE_PROJ, new String[] {CATEGORY_COLUMN_ID,CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE,CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT,CATEGORY_COLUMN_DATE}, CATEGORY_COLUMN_ID + "=" + rowId, null,
                        null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;

    }

    public Cursor fetchAllProjects() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE_PROJ, new String[] {CATEGORY_COLUMN_ID, CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE, CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT, CATEGORY_COLUMN_DATE }, null, null, null, null, null,null);
    }

     public void close() {
            mDbHelper.close();
        }

     public long createProject(String title, String content, String date) {
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE , title); 
            initialValues.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT, content);
            initialValues.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_DATE, date);
            return mDb.insert(DATABASE_TABLE_PROJ, null, initialValues);
        }

      public boolean updateProject(String title, String content, String date) {
            ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
            args.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE, title);
            args.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_CONTENT, content);
            args.put(CATEGORY_COLUMN_DATE, date);
            return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE_PROJ, args, CATEGORY_COLUMN_TITLE + "=" + title, null) > 0;
        }

    public GinfyDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
        String packageName = mCtx.getPackageName();
        DB_PATH = String.format("//data//data//%s//databases//", packageName);

        try {
             externalDbStream = mCtx.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

     public GinfyDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
            mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
            mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }
```

MY listactivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item2);
        lv =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        mDbHelper = new GinfyDbAdapter(this);

        mDbHelper.open(); 

        fillData();
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());


    }
```

My logcat error

```
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ibetter.Ginfy/com.ibetter.Ginfy.YourPrayerActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5): , while compiling: PRAGMA journal_mode
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForString(SQLiteConnection.java:627)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setJournalMode(SQLiteConnection.java:313)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.setWalModeFromConfiguration(SQLiteConnection.java:287)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:215)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at com.ibetter.Ginfy.GinfyDbAdapter$DatabaseHelper.openDataBase(GinfyDbAdapter.java:193)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at com.ibetter.Ginfy.GinfyDbAdapter$DatabaseHelper.onCreate(GinfyDbAdapter.java:101)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at com.ibetter.Ginfy.GinfyDbAdapter.open(GinfyDbAdapter.java:276)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at com.ibetter.Ginfy.YourPrayerActivity.onCreate(YourPrayerActivity.java:118)
10-04 06:26:47.273: E/AndroidRuntime(1075):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
```

My activity has stopped now,i searched in google it shows error in open function.

Comment: What did you use to create that pre-populated database? It seems that your database is locked as seen in the logCat error: `database is locked`

Comment: @Razgriz actually i want to use manual database values also,i want to copy the database data and stored and populated

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to open the same database twice and that leads to a conflict

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5)
```

ie. In simple words, it seems your database is already open when you try to open it again.So Please check, if you forgot to close the database after you have opened it somewhere.

Comment: what i want dude,i want to copy the assets database values and put in new one,after that if i created it has to be come remaining like that

Comment: i felt that i am using opendatabase also open() function also,that might may be create problem